# Using Beltrami Identity on $ F=\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y^2} $

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The problem is to make the following integral stationary:
$$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y^2}dx $$
since the functional doesn't depend explicitly on x, I decided to try Beltrami Identity:
$$ F-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=k $$
thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y^2}-y'\left(\frac{y'}{y^2\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right) &= k\\
                                                                 y' &= \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2y^4}}{ky^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
and I get
$$
\begin{aligned}
y = \int \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2y^4}}{ky^2} dx &= \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2y^4}}{ky^2} \int dx\\
                                       y &= \frac{x \sqrt{1-k^2y^4}}{ky^2}+C
\end{aligned}
$$
I think there's some errors somewhere, but I'm not sure.
Is this answer correct?

Comment: The expected result is here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity#Solution_to_the_brachistochrone_problem . I think that the derivative is wrong.

Comment: I don't quite catch that. Isn't the integrand in brachistochrone problem different than this?

Comment: Sorry, probably I was not so clear. If you replace $y$ with $y^4$ in the denominator you'll find that the equation to integrate is $y^4(1+{y'}^2)=k$